# How should I perform Tasleem when joining late

Tags: salat, sunni

How should I perform the tasleem on the fourth rakat when I join late in jamaat.
Lets say on the third rakat? Do I complete it as everyone does and then do the remaining missed rakat? 
Do the missed rakat after the group finished and then do the complete dua including tashahhud?

Comment: May you please provide also from what view you want the answer(shia-sunni). Currently it might get closed as opinion based.

Comment: from a sunni perspective

Answer (score -1):

Assalamualaikum,

You will wait for the Imam to do salaam, as soon as the Imam has said the salaam you will stand up (without doing Salaam) and pray the remaining Rakaats.

And Allah Knows Best.